# Rxjs merge two observables with nested array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using angular *ngFor to display a list of users from an endpoint. Now I want to update the picture of each user after rendering the list. But the API to get the picture gets the picture by user Id. So I have to iterate the list and load the image for each user.  I am not sure which RXJS operator I can use to achieve this and also how to update the nested users list array.

**Get users list data response - `Observable<IUsersList>` 1**

```json
{
   "message":"Success",
   "data":{
      "users":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "firstname":"Bill",
            "dateAdded":"2022/02/01",
            "picture":"assets/default.png"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "firstname":"Steve",
            "dateAdded":"2022/02/01",
            "picture":"assets/default.png"
         }
      ],
      "totalPages":1,
      "totalElements":2,
      "last":true
   }
}
```

**Get picture by id response -  `Observable<IPicture>`**

```json
{
   "id":1,
   "picture":"remote.link/bill.png"
}
```

Here's my attempt, but it's failing. The users observable changes to picture observable  when I merge it. So in the subscribe next function there's errors.

```
this.userService.getUsers(params).pipe(
mergeMap(res => res.data.users.map(user => this.pictureService.getById(user.id)) )
).subscribe({
    next: res => {
      this.list = res.data.users;
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.total = res.data.totalElements;
    },
    error: () => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    },
})
```

Kindly help.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? To perform `this.pictureService.getById(user.id)` for all retrieved users simultaneously?

Comment: Hi @kellermat my goal is to asynchronously get the picture for each user after the list of users has loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could append an observable `picture$` property to each user that emits the "default" picture immediately, then the picture result from the service call:

```
const users = response.data.users.map(
  user => ({
    ...user, 
    picture$: this.pictureService.getById(user.id).pipe(
      map(({picture}) => picture),
      startWith(user.picture)
    )
  })
);
```

Then, just unwrap using the `async` pipe in the template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of list">
  <img [src]="user.picture$ | async">
  <span> {{ user.firstname }} </span>
</div>
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75225874?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.

Comment: This is a clever solution!  One nice addition would be to have a loading image so the UI doesn't jump around.  You could do that in the startWith.  Also the pictureService should cache responses so if a picture is reloaded it doesn't have to keep calling the service.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a mixture of `switchMap` and `forkJoin` to merge the results of all your requests:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

  this.pictureService.getUsers(params)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((userListObj) => {
        // Create a list of observables that will result in completed User objects:
        const obs = userListObj.data.users.map((user) => this.extendUser(user));        
        return forkJoin([of(userListObj), forkJoin(obs)]);
      }),
      // Add the completed User-objects to the IUsersList wrapper:
      map(([userListObj, users]) => ({...userListObj, data: {...userListObj.data, users: users }})),
      tap((res) => {
        this.list = res.data.users;
        this.total = res.data.totalElements;
      }),
      finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false))
    )
    .subscribe();
}

extendUser(user: User) {
  // Assign the updated picture-url, which is fetched via 'getById()'
  return this.pictureService.getById(user.id).pipe(
    map((p) => ({ ...user, picture: p.picture }))
  );
}
```

Comment: it's not neccessary add the userListObj to the forkJoin.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a delay from you can do this with **switchMap** and **concatAll** or **mergeAll**.  Both **concat** and **merge** will execute the inner observables one by one, but **concat** will preserve the order where **merge** will run everything at once and not care about order.

```
this.userService.getUsers(params).pipe(
  map(res => res.data.users.map(user => this.pictureService.getById(user.id).pipe(
     map(img => ({...user, picture: img.picture }))
  ))),
  concatAll(),
  toArray()
)
```

The problem here is that this could be slow.  You could lazy load the images and update the array as images are loaded.

```
getUsersRequestSubject = new Subject<GetUserParams>();

private getUserData$ = getUsersRequestSubject.pipe(
  switchMap(p => this.userService.getUsers(p)),
  map(users => users.map(x => ({ ...x, picture: '/assets/notfound.png' }))),
  shareReplay()
);

/** Return each image individually. */
private getImage$ = getUserData$.pipe(
  map(users => users.map(user => this.pictureService.getById(user.id))),
  concatAll()
);

users$ = merge(
  this.getUserData$.pipe(map(users => (_) => users)),
  this.getImage$.pipe(map(img => (users) => {
    users.find(x => x.id === img.id)?.picture = img.picture;
    return users;
  }))
).pipe(
  startWith((_) => []), // optional if you want an initial value.
  scan((users, reducer) => reducer(users), [])
);
```

Here's what's happening:

- When the user list needs to be updated call **geUsersRequestSubject.next(params)**.
- Once that happens **getUserData$** executes (as long as **user$** is subscribed to).  This retrieves the users and sets the picture value to a not found image.
- **getImage$** will use the result of **getUserData$** to emit picture data one by one to.
- **user$** will use a merge of observables that return reducer functions.  The one from **getUserData$** will replace the users array, while the one from **getImage$** will update the users array with the image.
- These reducers are executed by the **scan** function, which will pass the prior state into the reducer function to get the next state.

If you haven't gathered what will happen is that the user list will update with the result of the user api call immediately with each user having a not found image.  Then as the api calls to retrieve images execute, each not found image will get replaced.

Comment: I love your idea of get the "image" one to one.

Answer (score -2):

```
  data$ = this.service.getData().pipe(

    //from the response get only the "users"
    map((userListObj: any) => userListObj.data.users),
    
    //use switchMap to use forkJoin to execute
    //an array of observables
    switchMap((users: any[]) => {
      return forkJoin(

        //see how convert the array of users
        //in an array of observables
        users.map((user: any) => this.service.getPictureById(user.id))
      ).pipe(
        
        //transform the array of response using the 
        //users. see how use map

        map((pictures: any[]) =>
          pictures.map((x: any, index: number) => ({
            ...users[index],
            picture: x.picture,
          }))
        )
      );
    })
  );
```

Don't confused, the `map((userListObj: any)=>..` and the `map((pictures: any[]) =>` are rxjs/operator, the others map `users.map((user: any) =>` and `pictures.map((x: any, index: number)` are map of one array.

**Update** getting the idea of Daniel Gimenez I made [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vda9aa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fone.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftwo.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fthree.component.ts)